# How to use .text() method in a variable with javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clicklistener

Im new to Jquery and i need to convert this js file from js to Jquery. The code i provided probably has many simple mistakes, but i am getting the syntax error on  `var textnode = $(.text(task.value));` (If there is any extra mistakes please let me know)

```
  var buttontask = $("#buttontask");
  var task = $("#task");
  var list1 = $("#list1");
  var Delete = $("#delete");
  var Delete1 = $("#delete1");

  buttontask.on('click', function () {
  var newE = $('<li></li>');
  var textnode = $(.text(task.value));
  var buttondelete = $('#DIV');
  var textnodeX = $(.text('X'));


  Delete.appendChild(buttondelete);
  newE.appendChild(textnode);
  buttondelete.appendChild(textnodeX);

  newE.on('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  });

  buttondelete.on('click', function(){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    newE.parentNode.removeChild(newE);
  });
```

code i want to convert to jq

```
var buttontask = document.getElementById("buttontask");
var task = document.getElementById("task");
var list1 = document.getElementById("list1");
var Delete = document.getElementById("delete");
var Delete1 = document.getElementById("delete1");

buttontask.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var newE = document.createElement('LI');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.value);
  var buttondelete = document.createElement('DIV');
  var textnodeX = document.createTextNode('X');
```

Comment: task is not defined.also if it is class concat properly `$("."+varhere)`

Comment: sorry It is i just didnt include that part of the code

Comment: can you please include ALL relevant code to the OP

Comment: yea its updated

Comment: is it a class name? then use `$("."+task.val())`

Comment: task is an ID that is linked to an input feild. what ever the user types in, is what task.value should equal

Comment: $('#task').val()

Comment: `$(.text(task.value));` im referring to this why do you have `.` at the start I am guessing you mean class in this one so you need to concat properly. `task.val()` this will give you the value of the input with ID task since it is already defined as a var

Comment: dude i honesly dont know why i put a dot there... but now its saying text is not defined, i removed the dot btw

Comment: `.text()` is method. Can you include all relevant code and explain more what you want so we can help. It is unclear what you want this might be close as unclear question

Comment: I included the code that i want to convert at the bottom

Comment: then i guess all you need is `task.val()` this will give you the value of input with ID task. since task is var you need to get the value using `.val()` assuming that it is an input. if it not an input and you want to get its text then you need `task.text()`

Comment: ok so i think thats working, but now im getting error on $(.text('X')); which i want to had an "X" to a created element

Comment: `$(body).append('<span>X</span>')` to create a span with letter X

Comment: Does it append as a child to the span element?

Comment: yes it is child of span. it is inside span a text node with value X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If   $("#task") refers to a textarea you need to use   $("#task").text() to store its value. if it refers to an text input, you can use  $("#task").val();

Also be careful of using word delete for variables names in javascript, I know that the lower case version is reserved.